# Use renovate to update git submodule branch and commit

Tags: git, git-submodules, renovate

I am using renovate to update a git submodule, this configuration works fine.

```
{
    "$schema": "https://docs.renovatebot.com/renovate-schema.json",
    "git-submodules": {
        "enabled": true,
        "versioning": "git",
        "fileMatch": [
            "(^|/)\\.gitmodules$"
        ]
    }
}
```

I introduced branches to my `.gitmodules` file and I am trying to figure out how to make renovate update the branch to the latest (as well as the commit).

```
[submodule "my_submodule"]
    path = path/to/submodule
    url = submodule_url
    branch = release/2.0
```

I tried to change `"versioning": "git"` to `"versioning": "semver"` and `"versioning": "regex:^release/(?<major>\\d+)(\\.(?<minor>\\d+))"`.